# How to stretch a text field to width of parent div with padding?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, width

I cannot figure out how to stretch a text field to the size of it's parent div with 20px of padding?

HTML

```
 <div id="new-post-background"> 
  <h2 class="form-title">Create a Listing</h2>
  <div class="container">
    <h2 class="field-title">Item Title</h2>
    <%= f.text_field :title, :class => 'text-field from-control'%>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#new-post-background {
  background-color: #F2F2F2;
  min-height: 600px;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}

.form-title {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 20px;
  margin: auto;
}

.field-title {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-variant: small-caps;
  text-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}

.text-field {
  font-size: 20px;
  display: block;
  width: inherit;
}
```

I am using Bootstrap for front end, and as you can see there are elements rendered using Rails.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: One thing I notice is you are missed the class `form-control` for your text-field.

Comment: Not only that, but I see no bootstrap CSS grid rules, e.g. .col-m4 or whatever. In this case, if you want the div to stretch across the page within a parent container, you should have a .col-m12 (or some other bootstrap grid column designation).

Answer (score 0):

The parent div is `container`, therefore:

```
.container { padding: 20px; }
.text-field { width: 100%; }
```

Or if you just wanted the input and not the field title to have padding then add an additional container div:

CSS:

```
.field-container { padding: 20px; }
.text-field { width: 100%; }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <h2 class="field-title">Item Title</h2>
  <div class="field-container">
    <%= f.text_field :title, :class => 'text-field from-control'%>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you are using bootstrap then the html is different anyway so you should refer to the [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms).